# Is there any way to automatically set Debug True Django application

Tags: django, debugging, localhost, pythonanywhere, drf-yasg

I have a Django API that is being deployed in PythonAnywhere.
For that, I can not let the default option in `settings.py` as `True`:

```py
DEBUG=True
```

However, the app also has a Swagger page using [drf-yasg](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg) library. For that to work locally, I have to set the debug option as true.

However is being troublesome to maintain it, and I often mistakenly commit it as True to the repository.

Is there anyway I could manage this option so whenever I am running locally, it will automatically set it to `True`, but leave it as `False` by default?

```py
DEBUG=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose I use `python-decouple` package. To distinguish between production and development environments you can create one `.env` file with all production-related variables in it. In `settings.py` when retrieving the configuration parameters leave every `default` option with the one used in development. So when `.env` file is not present the default values are gonna be set.

```
from decouple import config

DEBUG = config('YOUR_ENV_VAR_DEBUG', default=True, cast=bool)
```

For more real-world use cases, please refer to the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/).